# Writing JavaScript Data To JSON File via AJAX or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, splice

I have the following code that displays information on a person in a table, and when a button labeled "learn" is clicked that information gets stored in a key/value type array that is then spliced into the specified JSON object.

All of this works just fine, but I want to alter the file that holds the JSON object itself, meaning I need to deal with server-side code. How can I take this  insertion into my JSON object and actually change the textfile it is stored in (such that if I were to open it, the new information would be there)?

My code is as follows -->

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="list.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Name</td><td class="name">Jenkins</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Job</td><td class="job">Accountant</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Size</td><td class="size">Small</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="description">average joe.</td>
            <td>
                <button class="learn">Learn</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".learn").click(function(){

        // look at jsonData in list.js and append this element to the items list in the 
        // first element, at the first index without removing any content
        jsonData[0].items.splice(0, 0, {
            name: $(this).closest("table").find(".name").text(),
            job: $(this).closest("table").find(".job").text(),
            size: $(this).closest("table").find(".size").text(),
            description: $(this).closest("td").siblings(".description").text()
        });

        // to show that it is properly appending the new information to the existing JSON object
        console.log(jsonData);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

list.js -->

```
var jsonData = [
  {
    name: "Friends",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Steve",
        job: "pro bowler",
        size: "tall",
        description: "Steve's my man!"
      },
      {
        name: "Jessica",
        job: "HR",
        size: "average",
        description: "a dear friend"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Co-Workers",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Martin",
        job: "my boss",
        size: "tall",
        description: "I don't like him"
      },
      {
        name: "Susan",
        job: "Intern",
        size: "average",
        description: "It's not like I have a crush on her or anything..."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So again, it can be seen in the console that jsonData has the information for "jenkins" added to it; however, the textfile itself remains unchanged and I would like it to reflect this addition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change files on the local file system using JavaScript (at least not in all browsers). 
I would suggest something like:

JavaScript:

```
$(".learn").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "save.php?action=save",
        method: "POST",
        data: { elem: {
            name: $(this).closest("table").find(".name").text(),
            job: $(this).closest("table").find(".job").text(),
            size: $(this).closest("table").find(".size").text(),
            description: $(this).closest("td").siblings(".description").text()
        }},
        success: function (data){
            console.log("Saved!");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP (save.php):

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_REQUEST["action"]) && $_REQUEST["action"] == "save" && !empty($_REQUEST["elem"])){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
        $data[0]["items"][] = $_REQUEST["elem"];
        file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($data));
    }
?>
```

This is just a very small example. Additionally, you should take care about escaping, checking for the fields, error handling, simultanious updates (more than one client) etc. - but it shows a possible way to do this.

Comment: This appears to replace all the content in the file with the added element.

Comment: @laroy I've updated the code above (forgot a `true` in `json_decode()` to handle objects as arrays, too)

Comment: when I read the json data to populate another table on my website, I refer to it as jsonData (as expressed in the code above). Assuming that "data.json" in your example is meant to be list.js, it replaces the part of the code that says "var jsonData = [" is there a way for me to overcome this replacement so that I can continue referring to the file in this way?

Comment: Unfortunality there is no way to read JSON data directly from a file into JavaScript, but maybe there is a litte workaround. Just read the JSON file with a simple PHP script so that it can act as your list.js:
`echo "var jsonData = ".json_encode(file_get_contents("data.json"));`